# URL rewriting to remove some directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link

http://sdpi.org/publications/files/Future_of_Sustainable_Development_in_South_Asia%20(M-24).pdf

I want to rewrite the above url to the following url

http://sdpi.org/Future_of_Sustainable_Development_in_South_Asia%20(M-24).pdf

thats is remove "publications/files/"

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: NO, i am not familiar with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your htaccess file should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^publications/files/(.*)$ http://http://sdpi.org/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect is working for you